# Creating a express website it throws me the following error

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I just installed node from nodejs.org I'm trying to create a simple website using express and when I called `express -c stylus test` or `sudo express -c stylus test` it shows me the following error `express: command not found`.

I installed express at a global level already.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: what OS are you running on? Also, did you install express with NPM?

Comment: Mac OS X to be specific 10.9.2

Comment: When I try via npm I give the following error                            npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'

Comment: you might have to run that npm install command with sudo permission

Answer (score 1):

Installing express as global for generating express app is now deprecated i guess. I run into these problem just a couple hrs ago. Check [Express website](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) they have a new express generator

Try the new Express generator

```
$npm install -g express-generator
```

then now you can run

```
express -c stylus test or sudo express -c stylus test
```